# Get запрос на android

Tags: android, запрос, get

В чем собственно вопрос , есть пример api сервера 
http://www.argusm-edu.ru/php/_api/_dev/api_search.php?search=&page=&q=

ответ получаю в виде

```
QID{#}QTEXT
•   QID – уникальный идентификатор вопроса
•   {#} – разделитель
•   QTEXT – текст вопроса
```

реализую это так пока на тестовом варианте

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.argusm-edu.ru/php/_api/_dev/api_search.php?search=%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c&page=1&q=20");

try {
     Log.d(Tag, "запрос отправлен");
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
     HttpEntity httpEntity =response.getEntity();
     String line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");
     Log.d(Tag, line);
}
 catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
Log.d(Tag, "ошибочка");
} 
catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
Log.d(Tag, "запрос не отправлен");
}
```

запускаю на эмуляторе android версии 2.33 все ровно запрос отправляется , ответ приходит
Запускаю на телефоне (версия 4.04) или эмуляторе версия 4.2 вылетает с ошибкой
В манифесте вроде прописано то что нужно

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Вот лог

```
04-03 23:15:00.366: D/TextLayoutCache(29273): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0 
04-03 23:15:00.386: D/libEGL(29273): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so 
04-03 23:15:00.396: D/libEGL(29273): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so 
04-03 23:15:00.416: D/libEGL(29273): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so 
04-03 23:15:00.416: D/libEGL(29273): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so 
04-03 23:15:00.596: D/OpenGLRenderer(29273): Enabling debug mode 0 
04-03 23:15:06.666: D/myLogs(29273): itemClick: position = 0, id = 0 
04-03 23:15:06.944: D/OpenGLRenderer(29273): Flushing caches (mode 0) 
04-03 23:15:12.266: D/myTag(29273): ппро 
04-03 23:15:12.266: D/myTag(29273): %d0%bf%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be 
04-03 23:15:12.276: D/myTag(29273): запрос отправлен 
04-03 23:15:12.296: D/AndroidRuntime(29273): Shutting down VM 
04-03 23:15:12.296: W/dalvikvm(29273): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1108) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:580) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:512) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:490) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at com.example.myuniversity.xochyznat$1.onClick(xochyznat.java:70) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3534) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
04-03 23:15:12.306: E/AndroidRuntime(29273):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
04-03 23:15:12.396: D/dalvikvm(29273): GC_CONCURRENT freed 254K, 5% free 9012K/9415K, paused 2ms+2ms 
04-03 23:16:12.946: I/Process(29273): Sending signal. PID: 29273 SIG: 9
```

Не подскажете в чем проблема?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ответ заключен в строке "NetworkOnMainThreadException". В новых андроидах нельзя делать запросы по сети в главном потоке. Нужно либо делать отдельный поток, либо AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

русскими буквами же написано android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException  =)

надо было бы знать, что с 4 версии андирода работа сетью ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО должна быть в потоке(не UI)